# How can I close all my app sound?

Tags: ios, audio

There are somoe buttons in a view of my app, and it will play a sound when user click one button . I want to add a swich in app settings view, when user close the swich, no sound will be played when user clicked the buttons. Then the swich is on, sound will be played again. What should I do?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to route all sound playback through a single class and add a property to this class for muting or sound skipping:

```
@interface Jukebox : NSObject
@property(assign, getter=isMuted) BOOL muted;
- (void) playSoundWithID: (NSString) soundID;
@end

@implementation Jukebox
@synthesize muted;

- (void) playSoundWithID: (NSString) soundID
{
    if (!muted) {
        // …
    }
}

@end
```

Or you can wrap `AVAudioPlayer` and make it check some app-wide boolean flag before playing:

```
@implementation CustomAudioPlayer

- (BOOL) play
{
    return ([[AppSettings sharedInstance] playSounds]) ?
        [super play] : NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
if ([switch isOn]){
   [musicPlayer setVolume:1.0];
} else {
    [musicPlayer setVolume:0.0];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don’t think this will work, as the `MPMusicPlayerController` only affects the playback from the music library?

Comment: MPMusicPlayerController effect system sound. So if you mute musicPlayer volume, it will mute system sound. So this code will also work and it has worked for me. But of-course it depend on your requirement whether you want to implement this or something else.